# from .hdf to .geoTIFF of product MOD35

Tags: geotiff-tiff, matlab, hdf

I am trying to create a geoTIFF from an .hdf MOD35_L2, I am trying either a Matlab code, either I heard something about LDOPE-1.7 + MRTSwath but I am not really succeeding.

Have anyone ever tried to do so?

Answer (score 3):

I did it in python, with MOD04 however. Still, what have you tried in Matlab so far? 
I could get to

```
info=hdfinfo('MOD35_L2.A2017090.0340.005.2017090132804.hdf');
dsets = info.Vgroup.SDS;
```

but in the second line I received an empty raster.

Comment: I do not know python, so far I have used matlab functions:

meshgrat
geoloc2grid
refvecToGeoRasterReference
geoshow
and
geotiffwrite.

I do not know if there is another method to do so.

Comment: I will continue trying something. If you find a solution, please let me know.

Comment: I contacted hdf forum and they gave me a correction for my code. so here it is the right code to convert the MOD35 product to geotiff.
http://hdfeos.org/zoo/LAADS/MOD35_L2_A2017060_1010_005_2017060204002_hdf.m
with:
ftp://ftp.hdfgroup.uiuc.edu/pub/outgoing/NASAHDF/MOD03.A2017060.1010.005.2017060201617.hdf